# Checking if a link contains a word in array javascript

Tags: javascript, arrays

How to check if a link contains a word in array?

```
var substrings = ['connect', 'ready','gmanetwork'];
var str = window.location.href
if (substrings.some(function(v) { return str === v; })) {
   alert("true")
}
```

Answer (score 4):

I would use `str.indexOf(v) > -1` to check if the href contains the word in your array.

If you want to be one of the cool kids you can use the [Bitwise NOT](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Bitwise_Operators#Bitwise_NOT) like this. `~str.indexOf(v)`

```js
var substrings = ['connect', 'ready','gmanetwork'];
// var str = window.location.href
var str = 'somethingconnect.com'
if (substrings.some(function(v) { return str.indexOf(v) > -1 })) {
   console.log("true")
}
```

Comment: yes, let's be cool kids and `~str.indexOf(v)`. For the one who does not know: check **MDN ~ Bitwise NOT Reference** https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Bitwise_Operators#(Bitwise_NOT)

Comment: Never heard of bitwise before but thankfully it worked :)

Answer (score 3):

You may use:

- [`Arrow functions`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Functions/Arrow_functions)
- [`String.prototype.includes()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/includes)

As from [Docs](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/includes):

> The `includes()` method determines whether one string may be found within another string, returning `true` or `false` as appropriate.

**Example:**

```js
const substrings = ['connect', 'ready','gmanetwork'];
const str = 'gmanetwork.com';

if(substrings.some(s => str.includes(s))) {
  console.log("Value exists");
}
```

Answer (score 0):

```js
var substrings = ['connect', 'ready','gmanetwork'];
var str = 'http://www.example.com/connect-your-pc'; //url

if (substrings.some(function(v) { return str.indexOf(v) >= 0; })) {
   alert("true");
}
```